# How to add a class to and img if it's ID is equal to a spcified variable "count"

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery and need a little troubleshooting/ help with my code. I'm working on an image gallery. I have a collage of images and when I click on an image, it brings up a large version. When the large version pops up, I want to be able to click next (.right) and see the next (large) image of the collage. I have a var count that goes up by one every time the next button is clicked. Each collage image has an id of 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5, etc. When the next button is clicked, I want to add a class called "count" to the image that has the id matching count. Then I trigger the click of the collage item with class "count".
Here's my script that doesn't quite work:

```
    /*".right" is the next button*/
    count = 0;


    $( ".right" ).click(function() {

  count +=1;
  var galleryInterior = $("#galleryinterior img");
  if(galleryInterior.attr("id") == count) {

      $("galleryinterior img").addClass("count");

      }




$("#galleryinterior .count" ).trigger("click");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/*".right" is the next button*/
count = 0;

$(".right").click(function () {
    count += 1;
    //remove the count class from current image
    $("#galleryinterior .count").removeClass('count')
    //find the next image with the id
    var galleryInterior = $("#" + count);
    //add the class and trigger the click event
    galleryInterior.addClass("count").click();
});
```

- When you say `galleryInterior.attr("id") == '1'`, it compares the class of the first image with 1
- `$("galleryinterior img").addClass("count");` adds the class count to all images instead of the one with id in `count`
- Instead you need to remove the count class from all images, then find the image with id of count then add the class to that particular element and trigger the click event to it